# How do I sort an array of objects by multiple properties using BigCommerce built in handlebars helpers?

Tags: arrays, sorting, handlebars.js, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I have a requirement to sort an array of objects by multiple properties in a BigCommerce Stencil theme using their built in helpers before iterating over the properly sorted list.
**Can anyone please help me?**

My current code example:

```
{{#each (sortBy (after customer.addresses 1) "last_name")}}
    <div class="panel panel--address">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <li>{{company}}</li>
            <li>{{address1}}</li>
            <li>{{address2}}</li>
            <li>{{city}}{{#if state}}, {{state}}{{/if}} {{zip}}</li>
            <li>{{country}}</li>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Here I am iterating over a list of addresses in the customer's address book.  I omit the first address, then sort the rest of the addresses by last name, then iterate over the sorted list to display some information about each address in a panel.

This all works great.  What I now need to do is add first_name and address1 as the second and third properties.  This way if the user has multiple addresses with the same names the code should then sort the duplicates by address.

I was hoping for something as simple as
`{{#each (sortBy (after customer.addresses 1) "last_name, first_name, address1")}}`
But separating the string with commas or spaces just returns the unsorted list.

Documentation for reference:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/2a56bda466a81-handlebars-helpers-reference

Comment: From what I can tell from the documentation, I think you would need to supply a custom compare function to the `sortBy` helper to do the secondary and tertiary sorting. Is that something you are able to do?

Comment: @76484 I did see the option to supply it a custom function but was not clear on how to do that in the template.  BigCommerce does not expose their handlebars instance to be able to add additional custom helpers or anything so any additional JS would run after page load.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BigCommerce. How does your template function get executed?

Comment: I think they have their helpers registered server-side.  And I think stencil CLI compiles the templates server-side too in order to make that work.  So locally you just have the template files, but you don't have access to the actual handlebars implementation.  In order to run locally you have to use stencil CLI commands and connect to a bigcommerce store in order to compile your theme templates with data.

I'm not sure if that answers your question though.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you do not have code that executes the template function. If this is the case, I am not sure how to proceed with solving your issue.